# How to submit form without the page reloading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="submit()">
<input id="name" class="btn" type="file" name="pic" multiple>
<br/><br/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
<br/><br/>

Uploaded file: <a target="blank" href="<?php echo $fileurl;?>"><?php echo $fileurl;?></a>
```

and I have this script

```
  <script>
function submit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "", true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var params = "search=" + <<get search value>>; // probably use document.getElementById(...).value
    http.send(params);
    http.onload = function() {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to submit the form without the page reloading but isn't working for me.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: how...sample please

Comment: Also change you button type to ="button" and see if that helps.

Comment: changing the type to "button" didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes `event` property, on which you can invoke `preventDefault()`

```
function submit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "", true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var params = "search=" + <<get search value>>; // probably use document.getElementById(...).value
    http.send(params);
    http.onload = function() {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: you also need `submit` listener on your form  `form.addEventListener('submit', submit);`

Comment: Instead of `onsubmit="submit()"` do a `document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', submit);`

Answer (score 0):

**See this check function to stop page reloding**

**As you have requested I have given the full code**

```js
function check(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("stopped form submit");
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="check(event)">
<input id="name" class="btn" type="file" name="pic" multiple>
<br/><br/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
<br/><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: complete please

Comment: @vsol as you have requested I have given the complete code. I hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: I run the code, clicking on the button, no action was taken

Comment: @vsol this is the format to stop page reloading. please use ajax for submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
      $('#yourFormData').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

      var formData = new FormData($('#yourFormData')[0]);
      url ="your route" ;
      $.ajax({
      url : url,
      type : "post",
      data : formData,
      contentType:false,
      processData:false,

      success : function(data)
      {
          // success 


      },
      error :  function(y)
      {

        console.log(error );
       }
      });

    })
```

Comment: Upon clicking it reloads